# strange TypeScript error, ts2367 in value checking

Tags: typescript, tsc

I have a ts class like

```
class Vector3 {
    //-----PUBLIC VARS

    x: number;
    y: number;
    z: number;


    //-----CONSTRUCTORS

    constructor(x?: number, y?: number, z?: number) {
        this.x = x == undefined ? 0 : x;
        this.y = y == undefined ? 0 : y;
        this.z = z == undefined ? 0 : z;
    }


    //-----METHODS

    SetValues(x: number, y: number, z: number): void {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.z = z;
    }
}
```

and i write a unit test code as

```
function TestVector3() {
    var lhs = new Vector3(1, 2, 3);

    lhs.SetValues(1, 2, 3);
    if (lhs.x != 2 || lhs.y != 6 || lhs.z != 12) {
        throw "a";
    }
    
    lhs.SetValues(-1, 2, 3);
    if (lhs.x != -1 || lhs.y != -2 || lhs.z != -3) {
        throw "b";
    }
}
```

it make an error on 'lhs.x != -1' TS2367.
removing line 'throw "a";' will kill this error, how to fix it?

this error should not be happend, i think this is so stupid...

Comment: That's not a good way to write a test anyway. Why put two cases in one test? Why never check the initial values? What useful diagnostics does `"a"` or `"b"` give you about what went wrong?

Comment: @jonrsharpe thank you for the Reply. this just a sample for the mischeck, the point is, SetValues is already change   x's value, and the compiler insist on the assert, that is not right at all.

Comment: No, it's not right, but there's only so much the compiler will do. After you've explicitly thrown an error if `lhs.x != 2`, it assumes `lhs.x === 2`. [`assert.strictEqual(lhs.x, 2)`](https://nodejs.org/api/assert.html) would have no such implication for the compiler _and_ better diagnostics.

Comment: @jonrsharpe can i announce to the compiler that the method will definitely change the value? can tsc do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The control flow analysis is indeed wrong in this case, because it is optimistic and assumes that `SetValues` does not mutate the class instance.
However, this is intentional behaviour: see [Trade-offs in Control Flow Analysis #9998](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/9998)

Apart from that your code does not make sense to me. It will always throw "a" and the rest of the code is never reached.

If your code is really a test-code, then you should anyway have dedicated test-functions for each case.

As a nasty workaround you could use `@ts-ignore`

```js
    // @ts-ignore
    if (lhs.x != -1 || lhs.y != -2 || lhs.z != -3) {
        throw "b";
    }
```

[Playground example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=41&ssc=6&pln=38&pc=1#code/MYGwhgzhAEBqCmwAuB7ATgZmgbwLAChojoB6EgWksoAUBVAIQBkBJAYTgEEAlAZQIOLQAHgC5oAOwCuAWwBG8NAG4BxAJ5ipchcsLEAXhpnyl-fCqJkqlVgHkAcjwAqXWq0c3epwcBTiISNElkdAAKIQB%20Qy00ABpoVUiJIwU4vUTNYwBKHHNBaCQACwBLCAA6IWgAXmEq6slxABN4ADMi8XgG6HDoAAZoMSEdPOJCktLVKvja6Hqm1vbO7r6xVSHh-OKyvUntyrrGlraOrt7%206D01ogBfU1zLKwBZAFFHAAkbABE%20M10iHngkLAwCBJPAIGEosY4uoktFUpCFJkxAA3FBFTp4X55UZlCrVQa5QQ48aTVaEkabUq7c6XaA3fD0gjNerIIq%20aCOMGAxCoTAhbKY7y%20fzQEAFGDVdoAdzgPPQGBCAEY4gAmOIYTI6XJisr-QHA0Hg5XQNXQDW0orNaAhHXlaAAQmqKugAB8XaLxSTHdAAGyu9227bexUqgXkjZoFAygBEYGjtKu0DuJA9uOgJQkUegKCtSFUAAd4CavMRbXqgSCwSFyMbTebk9AIPAiwUkEh8xARGQAOZFQqSWSlHzSEjSIrASMQHNIEiOAvwHgTor5mclCCGkgATm3AA4GwABJAQchFbvidDwXKW622iremv%201Ne6rkZ1up9Bl8anJYokFSMxrI8a5PSggEIy%20Ccv4CDBHymRAA)

Comment: thank you for the reply, but this case is only for showing the runtime-value changing checking, if vector3 is variable, will it be fixed?

Answer (score 0):

```
if (lhs.x != 2 || lhs.y != 6 || lhs.z != 12) {
  throw "a"
}
```

Static code analysis has its limits. With the above check, you are narrowing down the types of `lhs.x`, `lhs.y` and `lhs.z` from `number` to `2`, `6`, and `12` respectively.

Ie once you reach the next statement, the compiler knows the values of `x`, `y` and `z` are `2`, `6` and `12` respectively. Because otherwise, an error would have been thrown and this statment wouldn't have been reached. But on doing

```
lhs.SetValues(-1, 2, 3);
```

the TS compiler can't know that this method call actually changes the values of `x`, `y` and `z`, so the type narrowing is still intact. And now the following comparisons seem useless, because the compiler still "knows" `x`, `y` and `z` are `2`, `6` and `12` respectively.

```
if (lhs.x != -1 || lhs.y != -2 || lhs.z != -3) {
    throw "b";
}
```

Comment: thank you for the reply, can i only disable THE value check on this status? i can't control user's program habit.

Comment: One possibility would be setting the properties directly instead of setting them via method. AFAIK you cannot *disable* type narrowing. There are some tricks which may or may not work in different versions of typescript, like for instance in Behemth's answer (which works, but to be honest I didn't dive into it, so I don't really know why, and if it does so for all past or future versions of TS)

Comment: strange solution, but thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Another workaround is to additionally check if `lhs` is truthy. That way you get rid of the narrowing.

```
function TestVector3() {
  var lhs = new Vector3(1, 2, 3);

  lhs.SetValues(1, 2, 3); 
  if (lhs && (lhs.x != 2 || lhs.y != 6 || lhs.z != 12)) {
    throw "a";
  }

  lhs.SetValues(-1, 2, 3);
  if (lhs && (lhs.x != -1 || lhs.y != -2 || lhs.z != -3)) {
    throw "b";
  }
}
```

Comment: wow, what is this magic?

Comment: @Behemoth Do you have any idea *why*  this works, ie why will adding the truthiness check prevent type narrowing?

Comment: @derpirscher it looks like instance null checking will break the compiling static assert

Comment: Yes, I think you kind of *reset* the control flow. In the `if` statement TypeScript will infer `lhs` as the initial `Vector3` and therefore infer `x`, `y` and `z` as `number`s again.

Comment: it could solve this problem in almost like hacking way, but thanks for the answer.